# Tomcat server is not starting if i make changes in server.xml in conf folder

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

Whenever I changed the `server.xml` with MySQL properties then tomcat server just blinking and stopping how to solve this issue

```
<Realm 
   className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
   driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root;password=root" 
   userTable="users" 
   userNameCol="user_name" 
   userCredCol="user_pass" 
   userRoleTable="user_roles" 
   roleNameCol="role_name"/>
```

Comment: @OP please add in the startup errors from the logs. Otherwise we can only guess about what the error might be.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, the issue that I can see is that your `connectionURL` is wrong, URL parameters are separated with an `&`, which with HTML encoding is `&amp;`:

```xml
<Realm 
      className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
      driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&amp;password=root"            
      userTable="users"
      userNameCol="user_name" 
      userCredCol="user_pass"
      userRoleTable="user_roles" 
      roleNameCol="role_name"/>
```